# What are the properties of ImageField in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have created a userUpdate view with a partial modelForm to update user data, which consists of an imageField.

Form in my template looks like:

```
<div class='field'>{{ form.photo.label_tag }} {{ form.photo}}</div>
```

Here `photo` is the `imageField`.

The rendered html view is:

[image]

But,

- I don't want the clear checkbox.
- How to get the url of the current image if one exists for the model instance?
- What are all the  properties of the `photo`? So, that I can individually use them as required.

Answer (score 2):

## clear checkbox

You need to change the widget from `ClearableFileInput` to `Fileinput`

```
# forms.py
from django.forms.widgets import FileInput

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
       model = User
       fields = '__all__'
       widgets = {
         'photo': FileInput(),
       }
```

> The default FileField widget is `ClearableFileInput`.
>   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#file-upload-widgets

---

Alternatively, You can render HTML manually for `file` type field.

```
<div class="field">
    <!-- show label of field -->
    {{form.photo.label_tag}}

    <!--  check for input type -->
    {% if form.photo.field.widget.input_type == 'file'%}
        <a href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ form.photo.value }}">{{ form.photo.value }}</a><br/>
        <input type="file" name="{{ form.photo.name }}" />
    {% endif %} 
</div>
```

## get the URL of the current image if one exists for the model instance

You can get URL of current image using `.` operator

```
# URL of the image
photo.url

# name of the image
photo.name
```

## properties of the `ImageField`

ImageField inherits all attributes and methods from `FileField`, but also validates that the uploaded object is a valid image.

In addition to the special attributes that are available for FileField, an ImageField also has `height` and `width` attributes.

> Read the official [**`docs`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#filefield-and-fieldfile) for the list of all attributes